# ASP.Net Identity Framework sign in after register

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have the following code to try and automatically log a user in after they register but for some reason it doesn't work.

The code hits the line:

```
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

But for some reason still doesn't log the user in. I thought the SignInAsync would have done it.

Anyone know why it wouldn't be automatically logging the user in?

```
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { 
                UserName = model.Email, 
                Email = model.Email,
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                PasswordHint =  model.PasswordHint,
                EmailConfirmed = true
            };
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, false);

                UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, AppConstants.Roles.Candidate);

                //create a candidate profile for this candidate.
                ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

                var savedUser = context.Users.Single(x => x.Email == user.Email);

                savedUser.Candidate = new Candidate();

                try
                {
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
                {
                    foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                            eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Value: \"{1}\", Error: \"{2}\"",
                                ve.PropertyName,
                                eve.Entry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(ve.PropertyName),
                                ve.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                    throw;
                }

                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Use `UserManager.Update(user);` after you add the user to a role.  Also, you are logging in the user twice in your code.

Comment: Thanks Jacob that fixed it. It must have logged the user in but not associated them with the appropriate role then redirected to the login page. Can you put your reply as an answer so I can give kudos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding or changing a Role or Claim, the `UserManager` will not automatically persist those changes until `UserManager.Update(user);` is called.